# Google Spreadsheets: Conditional Formatting if cells add up to more than 100%

Tags: google-sheets

I have a row where I am trying to allocate a budget by percentage. So for example, one month's budget is 5% and anothers is 10% and so on for 12 months. However, I would like to have some conditional formatting so that if the sum of these percentages equals more than 100%, then all the cells in that row turn red. How would I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your percentages are in `A1:A12` you just just put a conditional formatting rule on that range with the formula condition `=SUM($A$1:$A$12) > 1`.

Make sure to make it absolute references, otherwise the range inferred for A2 will be `=SUM($A$2:$A$13) > 1`.